# Does california SB 876 protect working homeless?

Tags: human-rights

I live out of my van in LA county. Im often harassed by security guards forcing me from safe parking locations, such as an out of general sight rear parking area at my gym, when not at work or while using those facilities. Other locations have proven unsafe and very exposed. Im not overnight parking there all the time just 2-3 times a week so as to avoid horrible'ness ln my fellows (which i speak to in the coming sidenote). I do not litter or damage the area.
sidenote:
Sadly... Some non-homeless persons call the police and provide those honorable officers false witness with outlandish calms just to have me forcibly removed from their entitled view.

I do not drink do drugs or leave my vehicle without causes that improve my physical or mental state.

-Im just chillin watching netflix till my next shift.-

Im hoping that at least i can stop the harassment from "over stepping" guards without wasting our LA county officers valuable time By providing some kind of documentation such as SB 876 homelessness.

Answer (score 1):

It provides no protection, because it was only [a proposed law](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billNavClient.xhtml?bill_id=201520160SB876), which died in 2016. However, the definition of "homeless person" is

> those individuals or members of families who lack a fixed, regular,
>   and adequate nighttime residence, including people defined as homeless
>   using the criteria established in the [Homeless Emergency Assistance
>   and Rapid Transition to Housing (HEARTH) Act of 2009](https://files.hudexchange.info/resources/documents/S896_HEARTHAct.pdf)

which doesn't distinguish between employed and unemployed homeless persons. That bill would allow homeless persons to use "public spaces", defined as

> any property that is owned by a government entity or any property upon
>   which there is an easement for public use and that is held open to the
>   public, including, but not limited to, plazas, courtyards, parking
>   lots, sidewalks, public transportation facilities and services, public
>   buildings, shopping centers, and parks.

Parking lot is explicitly included. Since this isn't a law, you're going to have a hard time persuading anyone that it matters what was in the bill.